# Como descativar las teclas excepto el F5? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como desactivar todas las teclas con excepción del F5 ya que sirve para actualizar.

Este es el codigo, lo malo es que se desactivan todas las teclas incluyendo el F5.

```
 document.onkeydown = function(e) {
         if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 86 || e.keyCode === 85 || e.keyCode === 117)) {


        }
        return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz una condicional para que desactive la tecla solo si el código de tecla es diferente a 116 (F5).

```js
const onKey = e => {
  if (e.keyCode !== 116) { e.preventDefault() }
}

document.onkeypress = onKey
document.onkeydown = onKey
```

Es importante que no solo uses `keydown` si no también `keypress`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias funciona.